# MySQL Automated Queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello **stackoverflow**!

Can I automate my database to create reports every 7 days (selecting data from table **X** and inserting it into table **Y**)?

Let's say that I have `reports` table (`report_id` (PK, AI), `advertisements`) and I want to select something from `players` table and insert it into `reports` table every 7 days

Comment: You can schedule in crotab if your environment is UNIX

Comment: you can use mysql Event Scheduler

Comment: MySQL EVENTs. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: Can I use math functions in Event Scheduler (like I want to sumarise everything from table Y's row and see the diff between them and new number)

Comment: If you can use the maths functions you require in a query then you can use the same query in the event - .